# How can I change Win 10 protected registry entries?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, windows-registry, windows-defender

- I'm trying to disable Windows Real-time protection on Win 10 Home Edition, following this [tutorial](https://mywindowshub.com/how-to-enable-disable-microsoft-defender-antivirus-on-windows-10/), I reached this point:

[image: step]

- where I get the **Error:** `error writing the value's new contents`, I also tried to change the folder permissions on the `regedit`, I'm also getting the error:

[image: error]

- is there any way to handle those errors and stop Microsoft real-time protection from running by force on my machine? thanks in advance

Comment: DON'T change permissions on sensitive registry keys! Doesn't the usual procedure work: *Start  > Settings  > Update & Security > Windows Security > Virus & threat protection > Manage settings*, switch all settings to Off.

Comment: @harrymc I did that already, but real-time protection starts automatically each time I restart even I edited some policies on `gpedit.msc` to stop that, but the real-time protection is still running!

Comment: You are better off to use an offline registry editor, they ignore permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has become very protective of its Real-time protection.
This over-protection might be a bug, but for the moment it needs strong
measures to disable.

The best way to disable it is to install another anti-virus.
Otherwise, the following procedure will disable it only until the next reboot,
but can be automated.

- Disable "Tamper Protection" in
  *Start > Settings > Update & Security > Windows Security > Virus & threat protection > Manage settings*
  (this can only be done from Settings, but needs to be done only once)
- Run PowerShell as administrator and enter the following command:

  ```
    Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true
  ```

  After this, the protection will be disabled until the next reboot.

You may create a PowerShell script containing this command and set the Task Scheduler
to run it upon logon with elevated permissions, for it to disable
Real-time protection automatically.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing on each startup with GUI manner, but that doesn't seem to be a permanent solution for me.

Comment: A permanent solution might not exist for the moment (if this is truly only a bug by Microsoft). The above solution will at least let you automate it until the GUI settings return to be permanent.

Comment: even after this command still the `Microsoft Defender Antivirus Service` running even though it says on the security center that it is off!

Comment: Did you also try in `gpedit.msc`, at *Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Defender Antivirus*, to enable "Turn Off Microsoft Defender Antivirus"?

Comment: of course I did, and the command in the answer above worked for few days, then I don't know how Microsoft runs the service by force again!

Comment: Do you mean that the above command is no longer effective? Or effective only for a while?

Comment: the command above worked for few days, then the Win Defender service started to work again!

Comment: It should be run again after every reboot to be effective.